# device memory its just full of system memory

Tags: internal-storage, internal-sd

My internal memory is full of system memory, I have 4 GB and all that is system memory. I cannot instal any apps, cannot take a picture. My phone is rooted. I also try to reset factory setting, but nothing happens.

what will i do?

Comment: We might be able to help you if you can provide some more details: What device is it? What Android version? Also, please include the output of the `df` command (via a terminal app or `adb shell`). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your whole 4GB memory is in System Partition. 
If your bootloader is unlocked Download [TWRP Recovery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jmz.soft.twrpmanager&hl=en) and install it. Then reboot into recovery and repartition your System. 500MB-1GB is enough for System Partition.